# Appending a Numpy array to a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am new to Python and even newer to Numpy so apologies if I've made a blunder somewhere.

Essentially I am taking a list of angles (of indeterminate length) calculating an array based on trig functions of those values, and then creating a new list where at each index is a "trig array" corresponding to the index of the value that created it in the angles list.

Currently the loop calculates the correct arrays and prints them one at a time as expected however, the final output of the function is a single array rather than a list of each array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
            def tmatrices(angles):
                for angle in angles:
                    tmatrices = []
                    cos = math.cos(angle)
                    cos2 = (math.cos(angle)) ** 2)
                    sin = math.sin(angle)
                    sin2 = (math.sin(angle)) ** 2)
                    T = np.array( (((cos2), (sin2), (sin*cos)), ((sin2), (cos2), ((-sin) * cos)), ((-2 * sin * cos), (2 * sin * cos), (cos2 - sin2))) )
                    print (T)
                    tmatrices.append(T)
                return tmatrices
```

Comment: Your first line in the loop resets `tmatrices` at every iteration.

Comment: Of course thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a bit of a blunder and

```
tmatrices = []
```

should probably be outside the loop?

That said, you might prefer to use numpy more numpythonically and go for

```
import numpy


def tmatrix(angles):
    cos  = numpy.cos(angles)[numpy.newaxis, :]
    cos2 = cos**2
    sin  = numpy.sin(angles)[numpy.newaxis, :]
    sin2 = sin**2
    T = numpy.concatenate( (cos2, sin2, sin*cos, sin2, cos2, -sin * cos, -2 * sin * cos, 2 * sin * cos, cos2 - sin2 ), axis=0)
    return T


angles = numpy.arange(0, 2*numpy.pi, numpy.pi/10)
print tmatrix(angles)
```

which will return a matrix whose rows represent the different functions and whose columns determined by the angles.

Comment: Ok so I'm not entirely sure what is happening within this code (my experience is limited, however after a quick check, doesnt this mthod create one large matrix as opposed to a list of seperate distinct matrices?

Comment: Yes, it creates a large matrix. This might feel like a less obvious way of doing things, but it allows you to perform operation on the whole matrix in one go.